# Using cookies to alter currency with scrapy request

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, cookies, python-requests, scrapy

I am trying to extract data from this [url](https://www.carflexi.com/en-us/carselection/AR-LCAAAAAAAAApNjr0KwkAQhN9l6gvsXn5M1iqohZUSkweImqjgD6LYhLy7c0UgcMUcM7PzDXjBBrSwRByOMHjxGkkWSVKrmggfHE4zR3XunGGxjwuHbhI9LE8K73CZxJXtVblm-ka1aSqqO8znDg-YZqkLGBo7vOmL0m7DYveMmgM_Hx7imS8rWpDzB1swQmqU22q_q-rQCPSBYBlGw0IqzOk4_gFLkZV45QAAAA2). And below is the code which I've written to get this done.

```
cookies = {'.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.M6FGfmlbnTQ': 'CfDJ8A-eCRip5cVAs8-wkFU1H8dmFA0OIoxp6pQh1dcRvnpdNHKpKwFF2EhHSg5c-yqb-DriS6AIiwgnIpzyMiiphd42Un2v0-X6l8ePR4KkjG_CR2a_u6qrFOZNrRg0jrhliPOhyV6TKCtu6k-rn92lVMI',
 'uCurr': 'EUR'}

header = {'User-Agent': 'APIs-Google (+https://developers.google.com/webmasters/APIs-Google.html)',
 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}

formdata = {'query': 'AR-LCAAAAAAAAApNjr0KwkAQhN9l6gvsXn5M1iqohZUSkweImqjgD6LYhLy7c0UgcMUcM7PzDXjBBrSwRByOMHjxGkkWSVKrmggfHE4zR3XunGGxjwuHbhI9LE8K73CZxJXtVblm-ka1aSqqO8znDg-YZqkLGBo7vOmL0m7DYveMmgM_Hx7imS8rWpDzB1swQmqU22q_q-rQCPSBYBlGw0IqzOk4_gFLkZV45QAAAA2',
 'discount': 'AG51bGw1',
 '__RequestVerificationToken': 'CfDJ8A-eCRip5cVAs8-wkFU1H8fDgaTCPGKJ6FVhqBSItqEvJHfZlsE0bsh4EKYxRKIpb3CDhue0bRj0jOgsLjyHTIvvEolzWwGt1CDfRlgnXrfO8NZiEE3ZQhIyeVShd5-AxG-QhQp4zSE3WeWo7Fr40DI'}

url = 'https://www.carflexi.com/data/getDeals'

In [47]: fetch(scrapy.FormRequest(url, method='POST', headers=header, formdata=formdata,cookies = cookies))                                           
2021-04-25 19:21:11 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST https://www.carflexi.com/data/getDeals> (referer: None)
```

The problem is with currency parameter which is not working. I am trying to get data in `EUR` but it's giving me an output in my local currency.

```
In [48]: deal = json.loads(response.text).get('result').get('deals')[0] 
In [49]: deal.get('priceString')                                                                                                                      
Out[49]: '57,622'
```

Comment: This is called geofencing. The web server is checking the IP address of the client that connects to it and compares that to a list of known IP ranges located inside that country. You are not gonna get the euro currency you have to use VPN or Proxy. If you would like to use proxy, I will help you to provide a free selenium proxy script.

Comment: @MuratDemir please share the script. Also is there anyway to change the local computer's currency/country to get around this?

Comment: You can do it with proxy again

Comment: @MuratDemir would you please share the script you've?

Comment: Sure let me prepare for you

Answer (score 0):

Proxy nova is a free proxy provider we are trying to get the proxy address from that website before yielding the request. I used selenium to get the proxy IP.

```
import scrapy
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
class CarflexiSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'carflexi'
    allowed_domains = ['www.carflexi.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.carflexi.com/data/getDeals']

    def __init__(self):
        self.proxy_adress_is = self.proxy_adress()

    def proxy_adress(self):
        url = "https://www.proxynova.com/proxy-server-list/country-de/"
        opts = Options()
        opts.add_argument('--headless')
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=opts,executable_path="chromedriver")
        driver.get(url)
        time.sleep(3)
        proxy_ip = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tbl_proxy_list"]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[1]/abbr').text
        proxy_ip = proxy_ip.replace(",","").strip()
        proxy_port = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tbl_proxy_list"]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[2]').text
        proxy_port = proxy_port.replace(",","").strip()
        driver.close()
        return proxy_ip+":"+proxy_port

    def parse(self, response):
        url = 'https://www.carflexi.com/data/getDeals'
        request = scrapy.Request(
                url, callback=self.parse_product)
        request.meta['proxy'] = self.proxy_adress_is
        yield request

    def parse_product(self,response):
        pass
```

The proxy_adress function will let you connect to a Germany IP then you can scrape EURO prices.

I didn't use the form request. You will change it depend on your script.